# How to handle data with dependency on two different dates

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, anomaly-detection

I am currently dealing with a dataset that contains multiple date-time fields:
"buy-date" and "receive-date" which both have an effect on the prices and amount of offers made.
One example could be:

```
+------------+--------------+-------+--------+--------+
|  Buy-Date  | Receive-Date | price | volume | orders |
+------------+--------------+-------+--------+--------+
| 2016-07-13 | 2016-09-01   |   123 |     10 |    100 |
| 2016-07-13 | 2016-10-01   |   444 |      8 |     30 |
| 2016-07-13 | 2016-11-01   |   234 |      0 |      0 |
| 2016-07-14 | 2016-09-01   |   789 |      5 |     12 |
| 2016-07-14 | 2016-10-01   |   321 |      6 |     54 |
| 2016-07-14 | 2016-11-01   |   543 |     22 |     50 |
| 2016-07-14 | 2016-12-01   |   654 |     12 |      4 |
+------------+--------------+-------+--------+--------+
```

I wanted to use this data either in conjunction with an autoencoder or lstm or cnn to search for errors in the dataset.
But I don't know how to handle a dataset with two dates that influence the values.

I thought of just indexing everything from 0 to N and handle this as a normal sequence instead of a time-series. I might just use Buy-Date and Receive-Date simply as features for network instead of as indexes. E.g. convert 2016-07-13 to 3 Fields with "buy-year", "buy-month", "buy-day".

But how should I than go over the data? Can I still use a sliding Window? Should I just go through everything as if it were another kind of sequence without a temporal aspect?

Could that work or is there something I don't see? Is there a name for this type data-set? It doesn't seem to be a normal time series but it also isn't a panel.